# How to check your dynamo system?

Tags: dynamo, led-lights

I just bought my first hub dynamo (Shutter Precision PL-8) with dynamo headlight (Busch + Müller Lumotec IQ2 Eyc N Plus). After installation I figured out that light is not working. How to determine what actually is not working?

Comment: You need some sort of a voltmeter/continuity tester.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When checking a Dynamo system, there are 3 basic items which need confirmation:

1. **Power Supply:** Is your dynamo producing power? Checking this requires a multimeter, preferably with alligator clips on the wiring, and to spin the hub. Or there are specific tools, as well.
2. **Wiring continuity:** Are all connections tight? Are there any breaks/shorts in the circuit? This can also be checked with a multimeter. It is best done by isolating each section of the circuit to check, and then verifying the connections between the sections.
3. **Light Source:** Last, check your light source. Change the bulb if possible. Use an alternative 6v power supply to check whether the light head is functional or if there is an issue elsewhere in the loop.

Busch & Muller make a [rather expensive tool](http://www.peterwhitecycles.com/downloads/B&M%20Lichtchecker%20Pro.pdf) for troubleshooting a dynamo.

[image: catalog showing Light Diagnostic Tools and Mains power adaptor for B&M Lights]

Comment: Good points. Actually, I'd recommend your step 3 to be first: Disconnect cables from the dynamo, and connect a power supply instead. That immediately tells you whether light bulbs and wiring are good, which are the parts most likely to fail. While the dynamo itself can also fail, that is fairly rare in my experience.

Comment: What is the easiest way to find another 6v 3w AC power supply? I have only one hub dynamo.

Comment: I have made 5.2v DC power supply using four 1.3v batteries in series (http://i.imgur.com/R3ePfs4.jpg). Contacts sparking and heating up while light connected to it but still not working (http://i.imgur.com/Pab8RSi.jpg). Seems like it short circuit somewhere inside lights.

Comment: Yes, looks like short circuit. B&M are high quality expensive lights and I think it's unlikely that the problem is inside the light, so I would check the cables and in particular the clips where they connect to the light, perhaps one of the thin copper threads is making contact with the other wire.

Comment: Cable for lights is two separated wires and no way there could be short circuit while I connect it to battery pack just in front of my eyes. I think circuit inside lights could be damaged or something. What do you think?

Comment: I'd say you have an issue with the light. Have you contacted the manufacturer?

Comment: I am trying to contact retailer with that issue now.

Comment: Can that light damage my hub while connected? I rode about 2km with that.

Comment: Unlikely, as the power is generated by the hub, and thus any level of power in the system should be tolerated by the hub without issue.

Comment: One other option for diagnosis: contact peterwhitecycles.com and see if they've sold the diagnostic tool linked above to any shops in a reasonable range of your location.

Comment: Instructions for that tool says that light is checked with just 6v DC power supply. So with power adapter and multimeter (which i have) i can check my system completely.

Comment: Multimeter displays current (4-9v) on hub while i spin it stationary (with nothing connected). What exact measurements means that hub is in good condition?

Comment: Your current power supply is not 6v, correct? But, yes, otherwise you can check without it, if you are confident in your electronics skills.

Comment: There is no exact measurement. You are looking for an average of 6v. The hub doesn't spin consistently in a test situation, so the voltage produced will fluctuate.

Comment: My battery pack is 5.26v. Anyway i think contacts should not heat up while light is connected. Also I guess that power is enough to light it up a little.

Comment: I would agree that it should show some light. The heat could be poor connection to the contacts, or reversed polarity.  But I expect the light is the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for replies everyone (especially zenbike)

After light disassemble i found out what was the actual problem. There was a extra-solder where wires soldered into board that causes short circuit. After that extra was removed light have come to life ([YouTube](https://youtu.be/wMRKPbKN7gQ)).

[image: extra-solder]

Busch + Müller are high quality expensive lights, but seems like it is not expensive enough for simple quality-control testing

Comment: I bought one of their lights and the LED was loose inside the headlamp.  They're relatively expensive but I am surprised to learn that their reputation for quality is not good.

Comment: @YoloPerdiem I have to agree – I am so far very unimpressed with their build quality.